# creating a UIToolbar programmatically

Tags: ios, uiview, uitoolbar

I wish to add a UIToolbar programmatically to a view when a user clicks on a button (in my case when they zoom in on a photo).

It seems to work fine when I create the toolbar in the click method and add to the subview but if I create the toolbar in the viewDidLoad method, assign it to an instance variable,and add that instance variable later to the subview on click, nothing appears.  The debugger shows that the instance variable is a UIToolbar and is not null.  I didn't want to create and destroy the same toolbar on every click so I thought it was better just to keep it as an instance variable that I add and remove from the view as needed.  Is this the right approach?

Why is it visible in the one case and not the other.

Setup

```
@synthesize toolBar;

- (UIToolbar*)createToolbar
{
    UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 44, self.view.frame.size.width, 44); 
    UIBarButtonItem *shareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(sharePhoto:)];
    NSArray *buttonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:shareButton,nil];
    [toolbar setItems:buttonItems];
    return toolbar;

}
```

This works

```
- (void) clickMyButton {

    toolBar = [self createToolbar];
    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];
}
```

This doesn't show anything

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 toolBar = [self createToolbar];

}
- (void) clickMyButton {

    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];
}
```

Why doesn't it work in the latter case

Comment: Is your toolbar being retained with a strong association or is it assign  / weak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when `viewDidLoad` gets called, it is not guaranteed that the frames for your view and subviews are set. Try calling `[self createToolbar]` from `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` instead.

Comment: got it working but noticed a strange thing.  If I move the call to createToolbar into viewWillAppear, it doesn't work.  However, if I take the set frame line out of the createToolbar method and just add the line right after the call to createToolbar, it works.  Why would it not work when it's refactored into the method itself, even if it's still always called from viewWillAppear

Comment: weird... try doublechecking the ivar name vs the name of the variable used inside createToolbar. It might be that you are setting the frame of the ivar directly inside of the createToolbar method, instead of setting the frame of the toolbar that will be returned and then set to the ivar.

Comment: @Cezar appriciate!